# Measuring the Distance Between KDE Distributions with Different Bin Counts

Tags: distance, kernel-smoothing, density-estimation, nonparametric-density

I have two KDE distributions, each with a different number of bins. I'd like to compare them effectively, and I'm wondering if there's a recommended technique for this. Should I unify the number of bins, and if so, what's the best approach?

Comment: How do you like to compare the distributions? Like compute some sort of distance? Which metric do you use and why can it not be applied to your estimated distributions?

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus yes, I mean to calculate the distance between the KDEs

Comment: Which distance?

Comment: How are estimates defined? With bins creating a stepwise function looking like a histogram or as a continuous function?

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus discontinue function.

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus distance like: KL-divergence

Comment: What is your problem with computing that divergence?

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus does this divergence support the computation when KDE1 has 10 bins and KDE2 has 15 bins.

Comment: The computation of KL divergence only requires that a distribution density having the value zero, implies the other to be zero as well.